# .htaccess rewrite URL - change domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Wordpress multisite with WPMU domain mapping - that allows me to have different language versions on different domain.

I'd need to add a .htaccess rule, so that

`iouj.domain1.com/wp-activate.php?key=2b1447e2fe48f3af`

points to

`iouj.domain2.com/wp-activate.php?key=2b1447e2fe48f3af`

I guess I need Regex for this, but can't get it right...

Comment: Do you want to do a redirect from one domain to another?

Comment: no, I need to `rewrite` the URL, so domain2 content is displayed as domain1...

Comment: There is no rewrite if domain name changes

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using the WP multisite, and have domain2 content displayed on domain1. I need to make this work also for subdomains...

Comment: For WP multisite aren't `iouj.domain1.com/wp-activate.php?key=2b1447e2fe48f3af` and `iouj.domain2.com/wp-activate.php?key=2b1447e2fe48f3af` already showing same content?